# Cannot instantiate the type Android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I want to execute an AsyncTask and it's not working

```
public class httpConn extends Activity{

LoginClass newLogin = new LoginClass();
LoginClass loginRslt = new LoginClass();
TextView data,strConn,strTry,bfrTry;
Button btnFetch;
String[] baseUrl;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);


    data = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvData);
    strConn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvConn);
    strTry = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTry);
    bfrTry = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBfrTry);
    btnFetch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bFetch);
    baseUrl[0] = " ";

    new ReadDataTask().execute(baseUrl);

    btnFetch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            bfrTry.setText("before_try Success");


            strTry.setText("try Success");
        }       

    });


}

private abstract class ReadDataTask extends AsyncTask <String, integer, LoginClass>{

    @Override
    protected LoginClass doInBackground(String...params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        XmlPullParserFactory factory;
        try{
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);

            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;

            int responseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();

            if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                strConn.setText("Success");
                InputStream in = httpConn.getInputStream();

                factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
                XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

                xpp.setInput(in, null);
                int eventType = xpp.getEventType();

                while(!(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT))
                {
                    if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG &&
                            xpp.getName().equals("LoginModel")){

                        eventType = xpp.next();

                        while(!(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG &&
                                xpp.getName().equals("LoginModel"))){

                            if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG &&
                                    xpp.getName().equals("_ErrorFound")){

                                newLogin.set_ErrorFound(xpp.nextText());
                                eventType = xpp.next();

                            }else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG &&
                                    xpp.getName().equals("_UserID")){

                                newLogin.set_UserID(xpp.nextText());
                                eventType = xpp.next();

                            }else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG &&
                                    xpp.getName().equals("_FullName")){

                                newLogin.set_FullName(xpp.nextText());
                                eventType = xpp.next();

                            }else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG &&
                                    xpp.getName().equals("_ProfilePic")){

                                newLogin.set_ProfilePic(xpp.nextText());
                                eventType = xpp.next();

                            }else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG &&
                                    xpp.getName().equals("_ProfilePicExtension")){

                                newLogin.set_ProfilePicExtension(xpp.nextText());
                                eventType = xpp.next();

                            }

                        }

                    }

                }

                return newLogin;
            }else{

                return null;
            }

        }catch(XmlPullParserException e){
            Log.d("PULLPARSER","XML Pull Parser Exception",e);
            return null;
        }catch(IOException ioe)
        {
            Log.d("PULLPARSER","IO Exception",ioe);
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(integer... values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(LoginClass result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        data.setText(result._FullName +" "+String.valueOf(result._UserID));
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}

}
```

the error is in the line

```
new ReadDataTask().execute(baseUrl);
```

it's saying that

> Cannot instantiate the type httpConn.ReadDataTask

All what I want is to get data from webservice and parse it and show it on my screen

this is the LogCat

```
08-04 18:28:11.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22284): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
08-04 18:28:11.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22284): Process: com.example.httpmob, PID: 22284
08-04 18:28:11.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22284): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error      occured while executing doInBackground()
08-04 18:28:11.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22284):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
08-04 18:28:11.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22284):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
08-04 18:28:11.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22284):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
08-04 18:28:11.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22284):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
08-04 18:28:11.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22284):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
08-04 18:28:11.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22284):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
08-04 18:28:11.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22284):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
08-04 18:28:11.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22284):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:811)
08-04 18:28:11.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22284): Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
08-04 18:28:11.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22284):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6024)
08-04 18:28:11.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22284):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:820)
08-04 18:28:11.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22284):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16431)
08-04 18:28:11.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22284):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16431)
08-04 18:28:11.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22284):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16431)
08-04 18:28:11.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22284):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16431)
08-04 18:28:11.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22284):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:352)
08-04 18:28:11.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22284):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16431)
08-04 18:28:11.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22284):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16431)
08-04 18:28:11.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22284):    at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6600)
08-04 18:28:11.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22284):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3813)
08-04 18:28:11.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22284):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3671)
08-04 18:28:11.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22284):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3646)
08-04 18:28:11.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22284):    at com.example.httpmob.httpConn$ReadDataTask.doInBackground(httpConn.java:77)
08-04 18:28:11.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22284):    at com.example.httpmob.httpConn$ReadDataTask.doInBackground(httpConn.java:1)
08-04 18:28:11.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22284):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
08-04 18:28:11.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22284):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
08-04 18:28:11.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22284):    ... 4 more
```

Comment: it's abstract, that what abstract does.

Answer (score 3):

ReadDataTask is an abstract class. That's why you can't instantiate it.

> private abstract class ReadDataTask

You should remove the `abstract` keyword if you wish to create an instance of this class.

Comment: can you see LogCat ?! and tell me

Comment: @Baybars You can't manipulate the UI directly (by calling `TextView.setText`) in `doInBackground`. You can do it in `onPostExecute`.

Comment: I had an edit but it's been rejected (not sure why):  you can also extend the **abstract** class and provide implementation to all methods marked as abstract, thereby making it concrete and able to be instantiated.

Comment: @diginoise Yes, I know that, but I don't see any reason to declare that class as abstract and then create another sub-class in order to instantiate it, since you only use that class in one place.

Comment: @Eran understand. I was simply pointing out that in general abstract classes can be turned concrete by extending them. It is possible (although I don't know either way) that there is a valid reason to keep **ReadDataTask** class abstract and modifying it could be subverting some valid architectural decisions.

Comment: @Eran I'm already manipulating the 'TextView' in 'onPostExecute' not in 'doInBackground'

Comment: @Baybars you gave strConn.setText in doInBackground

Answer (score 0):

at a first glance:
a) it is abstract - you cannot instantiate abstract classes
b) this cannot even compile:

```
private abstract class ReadDataTask extends AsyncTask <String, integer, LoginClass>{
```

has to be:

```
 private abstract class ReadDataTask extends AsyncTask <String, Integer, LoginClass>{
```

Comment: actually I think the `integer` part does compile, it refers to android.R.integer, which is a class - although probably not what the OP want.

Comment: @ligi: Your answer is the same as the OP. Eh? Why include `abstract`?

Answer (score 0):

ReadDataTask is abstract class.

```
private abstract class ReadDataTask
```

Comment: While that seems to be the valid reason for his error it would be helpful if you could comment on the question if there is a solution or other way to do what he tries to do.